# Could not load file or assembly Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I added PayPalMerchantSDK to my project through nuget. When I debug it it works perfectly but on live version I am getting exception that dll is not included.

> The file or assembly 'PayPalMerchantSDK, Version = 2.14.117.0, Culture
>   = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 5b4afc1ccaef40fb "or one of its dependencies not found. The manifest definition found the assembly
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for and
>   determine where the error originated in the code more information
>   about this error. Exception Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1
>   [[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version =
>   4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089]]: The file or assembly 'PayPalMerchantSDK, Version = 2.14.117.0, Culture =
>   neutral, PublicKeyToken = 5b4afc1ccaef40fb "or one of its dependencies
>   not found. The manifest definition found the assembly does not match
>   the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I already checked:

- dll is in bin folder
- version, public key token are as required
- I added "dependentAssembly" to config
- I cleaned, rebuilded project deleted and added library through nuget several times

None of those helped. Any idea what else I can try?

Comment: did you check architect of assembly ?! when an assembly build to x86 and used if x64 mode , it thrown exception .

Comment: @Amir yes I checked it this one is ok

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Answer (score 0):

One of the dependancies of PayPalMerchantSDK might be either missing or not the same version referenced from PayPalMerchantSDK.

You might depend on the some component that PayPalMerchantSDK depend on but your dependant versions might differ.

Comment: I checked all dependencies. One thing is that I updated Newtonsoft.Json to version 6.0 and it updated automatically dependency in config with new version - but paypal is not being created there. Might it be a reason?